# Ansible: in case of identical variables

Tags: ansible

I have a file with identical variables, each belong to different service:

```
#integration/integration.yml

WEB:
aws_id: <some var>
aws_outh: <some var>

BACKEND:
aws_id: <some var>
aws_outh: <some var>
```

Each service has its own role/task:

```
roles/web
roles/backend
```

How to make ansible tasks for each service, to point to the variable that it belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the variables as `awd_id` and `aws_outh` within the respectiv role, you can do the following:

```
#integration/integration.yml

# indent the aws* variables to make them keys in the dictornary WEB and BACKEND
WEB:
  aws_id: <some var>
  aws_outh: <some var>

BACKEND:
  aws_id: <some var>
  aws_outh: <some var>
```

And in your playbook:

```
# ...
roles:
  - { role: web, aws_id: "{{ WEB.aws_id }}", aws_outh: "{{ WEB.aws_outh }}" }
  - { role: backend, aws_id: "{{ BACKEND.aws_id }}", aws_outh: "{{ BACKEND.aws_outh }}" }
```